# Get-WmiObject: Only select local (to the current session) objects?

Tags: powershell, windows-xp

I have Powershell code like this:

```
$disks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_MappedLogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='Z:'"
foreach($disk in $disks)
{
      [Console]::WriteLine("Object: " + $disk.Name + " is " + $disk.ProviderName );
}
```

But it selects objects outside of the current session, like other users on the terminal session. How can I limit this to objects only under the current session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter  "DeviceID='Z:' " | ? { $_.drivetype -eq 4 }
```

the where condition it's only to be sure is a network drive and not other kind of unit.

You can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) other drivetype code

Comment: That change to Win32_LogicalDisk seems to resolve it, although it gives less information on the actual disk. Thanks.

Comment: @JBurace I think you need the use of `ASSOCIATORS OF` read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384793(v=vs.85).aspx